# Parse XML file in Android

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing

I am developing an App for online voting in which the login process is through webservice which is in dotnet . The webservice part is ready and working but I want to see what response is getting returned.

```
URL url=new URL("http://www.example.com/login");
            HttpURLConnection urlconnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            String requestXML="<data><username>sachin.t@gmail.com</username><password>sachin</password></data>";
            urlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlconnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlconnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            urlconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/xml");
            urlconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+Integer.toString(requestXML.length()));

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(urlconnection.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeBytes(requestXML);
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            if(urlconnection.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream is=urlconnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader breader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String temp;
                String resp="";
                while((temp=breader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    resp+=temp;
                }



                Document respdoc=null;
                DocumentBuilderFactory docbuilderfactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docbuilder=docbuilderfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource isource=new InputSource();
                isource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(resp));
                respdoc=docbuilder.parse(isource);
```

From net I got this but I want to parse the response which is given below.

```
<login>
    <login_validation>"1/2/3"</login_validation> 
    ( 1-invalid username,2-successfull and 3- already voted)

    <voter_id>" 0/voter_id "</voter_id> 
    (if sucessfull then only voter_id else value will return 0)
</login>
```

Any suggestion ?

Thank You In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xpath (http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).  If I got you correctly your response is in "respdoc".
To select login_validation node you have to do this:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/login/login_validation";
Node loginValidation = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, respdoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

To select voter_id node:

```
expression = "/login/voter_id";
Node voterId = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, respdoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

After that you can do whatever you want with loginValidation and voterId.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is there anyway from which I can see the whole response like the console.log() in javascript ?

Comment: wel, you can add following lines: Log.i("Log_tag",loginValidation.getNodeValue());  to get response for loginValidation (in you case it will be 1,2 or 3)

Comment: I used something like this NodeList nl = respdoc.getElementsByTagName("login");
          
          
          // Get the response code
          Element response = (Element) nl.item(0);
          String responseCode = response.getAttribute("login_validation");
          Log.i("RESPONSE",responseCode);

Comment: Is this correct because I am not getting any log. Even if i used your above code to log response code its causing error the loginValidation is of type node and Log.i requires string.Thanks

Comment: Please try: Log.i("Log_tag",loginValidation.getTextContent());